# jquery - drag and resize window and keep modal in center?

Tags: jquery, resize

I have a website and its coming out great but I have one problem I can't figure out and can't seem to find the answer online.

http://ginosoftuscany.com/site/

click on a location - and you will see a modal pop over the picture slideshow...

Now the BUG ) when you are view a location drag the window size bigger/smaller and you will see the modal doesn't follow CENTER, it stays in one place and looks terrible..

Can I add some jquery to reset if the window size is being adjusted?

I will make a jfiddle if you need me to... figure it's just one line of code.

Thanks,
-O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you get the solution in your code

```
var winH = $(window).height();
var winW = $(window).width();
$(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);
```

extract it in a nice resize function

```
function resize()
{ if(current_id === undefined || current_id === false) return;
  $id = $(current_id);
  $id.css('left', $(window).width()/2-$id.width()/2);
}
```

fill your current_id var on popup open, and set it to false on close

after, only call resize on window resize :)

```
window.on('resize',resize);
```

Comment: Thanks I bet this is the answer, and I tried to add the code but with now luck.. I am probably putting it in wrong... I made a jfiddle can you add the code and update? http://jsfiddle.net/PnymY/

Answer (score 0):

If you mean zoom in/out (Ctrl-mouse wheel) cause look terrible, then problem in HTML layout, not in jQuery.
need #bellmore {position:absolute;left:50%;margin-left:-480px} in style.css

or $('#bellmore').css('left',calculateLeft) after each resize event.